# Look up where a NTFS group is used

Tags: active-directory, powershell, ntfs

We are doing some AD clean up and migrating or deleting old  AD groups and replacing them with our current naming stranded in AD. The challenge that we are running into is making sure we have the we have found all of the places with the previous group was used throughout the network specifically for file and folder access. for example let say we have an AD group called "old-Group" that is giving NTFS permissions on 4 different folder on 3 different servers. Is there a tool or script that I can install/run to identify all of the places where "old-Group" is listed in the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate:  [How do I find out how an Active Directory group is being used?](https://serverfault.com/questions/98092/how-do-i-find-out-how-an-active-directory-group-is-being-used)

However, see the below Technet Forum article with links, etc. that might help:

[How to tell if Active Directory group is used anywhere](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/378c25cb-ad4b-4d75-bf29-07a3fdb115a5/)